# Calculate Years and Months between Two Dates in Android

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, time

I am trying to display a custom text result between two dates. Here is the code in my Fragment, which return two dates:

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment {

  ...

  dashboardViewModel.productCategory.observe(this, data - > {
    if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
      int totalLos = Integer.parseInt(data.getData().getLos());
      Log.e("totalLOS", String.valueOf(totalLos));
      explainDays(totalLos);
      mBinding.los.setText("");
    }
  });

}
```

And here the code in BaseFragment which generate two dates:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

  ...
  public void explainDays(int totalDays) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date start = calendar.getTime();

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -totalDays);
    Date end = calendar.getTime();

    Log.e("startDate", String.valueOf(start));
    Log.e("endDate", String.valueOf(end));

  }

}
```

From the code above, I am getting these three logs:

```
E/totalLOS: 1233
E/startDate: Mon Jun 08 19:45:08 GMT+07:00 2020
E/endDate: Sun Jan 22 19:45:08 GMT+07:00 2017
```

How do I generate a response like for example **1 Year and 5 Months since 2007** between these two date results? the **since 2007** needs to be extracted from **endDate** from Log above.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Seriously, avoid the use of `java.util` whenever possible... What is the minimum API level you are supporting in this app? If you can use `java.time`, then do that. It's a lot better...

Comment: A division by 365 and 12 comes mind.

Comment: @deHaar Hi, any reason why **java.time** is better? the current min api is 19 by the way

Comment: @blackapps Hello, can you please elaborate? do you mind giving an answer below?

Comment: There are several reasons, e.g. consideration of daylight saving times and the possibility of using objects with or without respect to time zones or offsets. However, it's natively supported from Android 26, but there is a [backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) recommended to be used in lower API versions.

Comment: You learned in primary school to determine amount of months from amount of days. So what are you asking for? I forgot 31.

Comment: @deHaar Okay, thanks for your explanation. I'll write it down and try to migrate to java.time.

Comment: Good... use one or both of the classes `Period` and `Duration` if you want to calculate elapsed temporal amounts.

Comment: By the way... What is *since 2007* supposed to mean exactly? Since 2007-01-01 or since 2007-12-31? Is this all about the date part or do you want a difference in hours, minutes, seconds a.s.o., too?

Comment: @blackapps well I apologize if I wrote something ain't right. what I am asking for is that how do I get a result like for example, **1 Year and 5 Months since 2007** between *startDate* and *endDate* in BaseFragment. I was able to subtract the current date with days in integer passed to the function.

Comment: @deHaar *since 2007* supposed to be extracted from endDate *2007* is just an example from the endDate.

Comment: Well, 2007 is an incomplete because it has no day of year and no month of year, which seem to be mandatory for a calculation having a desired result like *13 years and 5 months*... But ok, I get you are receiving some kind of datetime object.

Comment: @deHaar I think from the generated Log above, the endDate result is Sun Jan 22 19:45:08 GMT+07:00 2017. It has a complete all-time requirement for a Date variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html)

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define format
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss O yyyy");

        // Date/time strings
        String strEndDate = "Mon Jun 08 19:45:08 GMT+07:00 2020";
        String strStartDate = "Sun Jan 22 19:45:08 GMT+07:00 2017";

        // Define ZoneOffset
        ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(6);

        // Parse date/time strings into OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime startDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(strStartDate, formatter).withOffsetSameLocal(zoneOffset);
        OffsetDateTime endDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(strEndDate, formatter).withOffsetSameLocal(zoneOffset);

        // Calculate period between `startDate` and `endDate`
        Period period = Period.between(startDate.toLocalDate(), endDate.toLocalDate());

        // Display result
        System.out.println(
                period.getYears() + " years and " + period.getMonths() + " months since " + startDate.getYear());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3 years and 4 months since 2017
```

**Note:** Instead of using the outdated `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, use the modern date/time API. Check [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) to learn more about it.

---

**Note:** The following content has been copied from [How to get start time and end time of a day in another timezone in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62235600/how-to-get-start-time-and-end-time-of-a-day-in-another-timezone-in-android/62236157#62236157)

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

> But don't we have any other option apart from switching to ThreeTenBP
>   Library?

If you insisted, I suppose that a way through using `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` could be found. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, so with what I know and don’t know I would prefer ThreeTenABP.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

---

Comment: I am unable to try your solution, these OffsetDateTime.parse(), withOffsetSameLocal() and Period.between() requires API level 26 but the current min api is 19.

Comment: @MAnsyori - Please check [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)

Comment: @MAnsyori See: [*How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706). And see [my graphic table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BcmB.png).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash interesting, everything's work. so firstly, I tried your code and added if the build version is or greater than 26 conditions, everything goes well. After that, I tried to run in API 22, it crashes. I use ThreeTenABP as you suggested, no need to change the code, just the imports, then it works well in API 22. I'm not sure about API 19 since too much error happens when testing the app I'm working on in API 19. I thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for the extra how-to pal. appreciate it.

Comment: @MAnsyori - You are most welcome. It is Basil Bourque whose posts inspired me to learn the modern date/time API. Later on, Ole V.V. too supported me a lot in this process. I do not have enough words to thank both of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can extract the month,day and year from both dates you can use following solution to calculate the exact difference between two dates.

```
            int sday=22 //int day of month here
            int smonth=1 //int month here
            int syear=2017 //int year here

            int eday=5 //int day of month here
            int emonth=6 //int month here
            int eyear=2020 //int year here

                resyear = eyear - syear;
                if (emonth >= smonth) {
                    resmonth = emonth - smonth;
                } else {
                    resmonth = emonth - smonth;
                    resmonth = 12 + resmonth;
                    resyear--;
                }
                if (eday >= sday) {
                    resday = eday - sday;
                } else {
                    resday = eday - sday;
                    resday = 31 + resday;
                    if (resmonth == 0) {
                        resmonth = 11;
                        resyear--;
                    } else {
                        resmonth--;
                    }
                }
                if (resday <0 || resmonth<0 || resyear<0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "starting date must greater than ending date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "difference: " + resyear + " years /" + resmonth + " months/" + resday + " days", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// in kotlin 
fun getDateAndYearsDifference(startDate: Date?, endDate: Date? = null): String {
    val startCalendar: Calendar = GregorianCalendar()
    startCalendar.time = startDate
    val endCalendar: Calendar = GregorianCalendar()
    endCalendar.time = endDate ?: Calendar.getInstance().time
    val period = Period(startCalendar.time.time, endCalendar.time.time, PeriodType.standard())
    val yearsAndMonths = PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroNever()
        .appendYears()
        .appendSuffix(" yrs", " yrs")
        .appendSeparator(Constants.COMMA)
        .printZeroRarelyLast()
        .appendMonths()
        .appendSuffix(" mos", " mos")
        .toFormatter()
    return period.toString(yearsAndMonths)
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend that no one uses the old `Date`, `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` classes anymore. They were poorly designed and cumbersome to work with. Your alswer seriously lacks some explanation. First of all, are the `Period`and `PeriodFormatterBuilder` from Joda-Time?  If so, please state so. As long as we don’t know, we can’t really use your answer.